# View not found for fragment when orientation changes

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin.android, xamarin

I'm writing an application in c# xamarin for Android. This code is universal and should almost work on Android. So the question is valid for both Java and c#.

So i got this application, where my MainActivity is my fragmentmanager. it is replacing fragments like this :

```
private void SelectItem(int position)
    {

        currentFragment = null;
        Fragment findFrag = null;

        string tag = "";
        var arguments = new Bundle();
        switch(position) {
        case 0: // <-- Home Menu item

                tag = "home";

                findFrag = FragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag (tag);

                if (findFrag != null) {
                    currentFragment = findFrag;
                } else {
                    currentFragment = new HomeFragment ();  
                }


            break;
            case 1: // <-- Picture Menu item

                tag = "picture";

            findFrag = FragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag (tag);

                if (findFrag != null) {
                    currentFragment = findFrag;
                } else {
                    currentFragment = new PictureFragment ();
                }

            break;
            case 2: // <-- Album Menu item

                tag = "album";

            findFrag = FragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag (tag);

                if (findFrag != null) {
                    currentFragment = findFrag;
                } else {
                    currentFragment = new AlbumFragment ();
                }

            break;
            case 3: // <-- Settings Menu item

                tag = "settings";

            findFrag = FragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag (tag);

                if (findFrag != null) {
                    currentFragment = findFrag;
                } else {
                    currentFragment = new SettingsFragment ();
                }

            break;
            case 4: // <-- Logout Menu item
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine ("You should be logging out");
            break;
        }

        FragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
            .Replace(Resource.Id.content_frame, currentFragment, tag)
            .AddToBackStack(null)               
                .Commit();



        _drawerList.SetItemChecked(position, true);
        ActionBar.Title = _title = _menuTitles[position];

        // Always close drawer when an item has been selected.
        _drawer.CloseDrawer (_drawerList);

    }
```

It all starts well and i can switch between fragments. But when i change orientation, it crashes with the following error message :

```
No view found for id 0x7f080014 (PhotoWapp.PhotoWapp:id/content_frame) for fragment PictureFragment{b52cb3b0 #1 id=0x7f080014 picture}
[FragmentManager] Activity state:
[FragmentManager]   Local Activity b52f3060 State:
[FragmentManager]     mResumed=false mStopped=false mFinished=false
[FragmentManager]     mLoadersStarted=false
[FragmentManager]     mChangingConfigurations=false
[FragmentManager]     mCurrentConfig={1.0 310mcc260mnc en_US ldltr sw320dp w533dp h294dp 240dpi nrml long land finger qwerty/v/v tball/v s.7}
[FragmentManager]   Active Fragments in b52f3150:
```

In my fragments i set the `RetainInstance = true` and but for some reason it can't find the reference to `Resource.Id.content_frame`.. What should i do to prevent this from happening?

The layout, where Resource.Id.content_frame is referenced from is : `Resource.Layout.Main`. And looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Resource.Layout.nameofxmlresource instead of Resource.Id...

Comment: You have no  idea what i am talking about.

Comment: Sorry for the prvious post. I didn't read your question carefully. One question, are you adding a starting fragment when your activity loads? The documentation for the replace method says: Replace an existing fragment that was added to a container. This is essentially the same as calling remove(Fragment) for all currently added fragments that were added with the same containerViewId and then add(int, Fragment, String) with the same arguments given here. If you do not have a Fragment added when your Activity gets recreated, your FrameLayout has no Fragments to replace